# ant junit not running single method with test target

Tags: junit, ant

I've got a build system running Ant Version 1.10.6
The macrodef that I've summarised below is constructed to switch on "run.multi" either it runs a single test method or it does something else (which i've not included as its not relevant).
The issue I have here is that I cannot get it to run just the one method 'test.method' - I've turned the verbose on and can see it all going in and being set correctly, but it runs all the methods regardless!

```
    <echo level="info" message="Single method=@{test.method}" />
    
    <junit printsummary="on" showoutput="true" fork="yes" forkmode="once">
        <assertions>
            <enable/>
        </assertions>

        <test unless="${run.multi}"
                name="@{test.single}"               
                methods="@{test.method}"
                haltonfailure="no" 
                haltonerror="no">
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
        </test>
```

And here is a portion of the output:

```
[echo] Single method=testSimple
[junit] Running com.test.util.TheTestToRun
[junit] Testsuite: com.test.util.TheTestToRun
[junit] Running on Java 9.0.4
[junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.473 sec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this was happening is either a bug or a feature in ant - around the fork option on the junit section. set 'fork=no' and the issue goes away:

```
    <junit printsummary="on" showoutput="true" fork="no" forkmode="once">
        <test unless="${run.multi}"
                name="@{test.single}"               
                methods="@{test.method}"
                haltonfailure="no" 
                haltonerror="no">
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
        </test>
```

A portion of the output:

```
[junit] Running com.test.util.TheTestToRun
[junit] Testsuite: com.test.util.TheTestToRun
[junit] Running on Java 9.0.4
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.12 sec
```